# How to select element between two id with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, addclass

I try to `addClass("selected")` on elements between two id, but it doesn't work.

I use `nextUntil()`.

I want to addClass **`selected`** on each all **`a`** between `d-61` and `d-64`.

**And I want to include the `a` of `d-61` and `d-64`.**

Here is my code :

```
<ul>
    <li id="d-60">
        <a href="#">60</a>
    </li>  
    <li id="d-61">
        <a href="#">61</a>
    </li>  
    <li id="d-62">
        <a href="#">62</a>
    </li> 
    <li id="d-63">
        <a href="#">63</a>
    </li>  
    <li id="d-64">
        <a href="#">64</a>
    </li>  
    <li id="d-65">
        <a href="#">65</a>
    </li>  
</ul>

<script>
   $("#d-61").nextUntil("#d-64", "a").addClass("selected");
</script>
```

Comment: It doesnt work because the `a` elements are not siblings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following

```
$("#d-61").nextUntil("#d-64").children('a').addClass("selected");​​
```

`.nextUntil()` processes siblings not children of siblings.

[Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/WH4cB/)

If you want to select the 2 outer elements as well, try :

```
$("#d-61").nextUntil("#d-64").andSelf().add('#d-64').children('a').addClass("selected");​​​​​​​​​​​
```

[Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/WH4cB/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/7AMzR/2/)**

```
$("#d-61").nextUntil("#d-64").add("#d-61, #d-64").find('a').addClass("selected");​
```

Comment: Yeah ! Looks good ! You don't use andSelf() function and it works great too. Nice, thank you

Comment: I have a problem. I would like to addClass `selected` on the same elements even I start with `$("#d-64").nextUntil("#d-61")`.

With your case, it added class for d-64, d-65, d-61.

Comment: What do you mean by same elements?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21637/discussion-between-steffi-and-adil)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#d-61").nextUntil("#d-64").find("a").addClass("selected")
```

http://codepen.io/joe/pen/tBxwi

Comment: @Steffi, you want to include 61 and 64?

Answer (score 1):

you can go over the list elements and add for each a the class.

```
$('ul li').each(function(index) {
    $(this).find('a').addClass("selected");
});
```